# Acceleration reaches speed of light?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, acceleration

Hi, I am thinking about acceleration. Let's think we have a force of $1$ N and a particle of $1$ kg, then acceleration will be $1$. So the speed gets higher every second and $c$ seconds later, *in Newtonian mechanics*, the particle will  reach the speed of light. In relativity, of course, something like that cannot happen.  So, what are the equations that describe acceleration in relativity?

Comment: I think you're looking for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_acceleration

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does the pilot of a rocket ship experience an asymptotic approach to the speed of light?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/87047/)

Answer (score 0):

Classicaly you have

$$
m\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\rm{d}t}=F
$$

In relativity, closer to speed of light the particle is, higher mass it gets. This increase of mass is expressed by gamma factor: $\gamma=1/\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$. See it is dependent on $v$. Therefore:

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}(\gamma m v)}{\rm{d}t}=F
$$

Comment: Very tempted to -1. It seems frowned upon on this site to use relativistic mass, and for good reason. It's more correct to say that its classical inertia increases as the velocity approaches $c$.

Comment: The question did not mention nothing about intertia so I did not want to complicate the answer introducing concept of intertia.

Comment: I thought that p/t=f not dp/dt=f

Comment: Is it clear that d/dt is derivative with respect to time? p/t = f is valid only in the case f is constant.