# If you fall for a long enough period of time, would you eventually hit or break the speed of light?

Tags: gravity, speed-of-light, relativity, faster-than-light

If you theoretically fall through an infinite hole, and since the longer or higher you fall, the faster you would progressively go, would you eventually hit or even surpass the speed of light, and if this were so, wouldn't we time travel from going faster than it?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/172786/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24319/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: No

Long Answer: [No](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_acceleration)

Comment: Tempted to flag this as "link only answer", but I'm a little confident that Wikipedia articles won't disappear.

Comment: It was also never meant to be a formal answer, considering the quality of the question. Just seemed like a little more creative than flagging it and writing "lack of research, look it up"